# Power Bi Cluster Chart Filter

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Hi I am trying to add a filter on this visual where I want to show the top 5 districts where the e stamps revenue is higher than the document revenue. Is there a way to apply this kind of filter on the visual

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aarqa.png)